# Why do I have to write line = reader.readLine() in while for the second time? I thought I have already defined it above

Tags: java

I would appreciate detailed answer, I have tried `while(line != null)` but it ends up with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    **String line = reader.readLine();**
    int a = Integer.parseInt(line);
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int intis[] = new int [500];
    if ( a > 0 ){
        while ( (**line = reader.readLine())** != null ) {
          count++;
            intis[count] = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());

        }

        for ( int i : intis ) {
            if ( max < i ) max = i;
        }
    }
    else {

  }
    System.out.println(max);
}
}
```

Comment: The first `String line = reader.readLine()` reads the first line of the input file. To read any further lines you need to repeatedly call `reader.readLine()` - the result happens to get put into a variable of the same name. Consider using a debugger or printing out the value of `line` at each point in time, to better see the interaction.

Comment: If you call it only once, reading only a single line, how will it read multiple lines in the file?

Comment: You don't change ``a`` during the loop, so the loop will loop as long as ``reader.readline()`` returns non-null. If this is more than 500 times, the ``intis`` array will eventually overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between *defining* the variable and *assigning* the variable that I think you're conflating.

On the first line, you're absolutely right - you're *defining* `String line` (and also *assigning* it the value `reader.readLine()`).  This is *different* from the invocations inside of the `while` loop, which reassign the variable to a different line every time.

Just know that your loop doesn't bound you against overfilling your array, which is why when you only checked `line != null`, you had your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  You may want to add something like this to it to be sure of that fact.  Your file may only have less than 500 lines, or it may have 501 lines.  This helps to guard against that; if you have less than 500 lines, the reader produces `null`; if you have more, then you stop because you have nowhere else to put the data.

```
while(line = reader.readLine() != null && count < inits.length) {
    // logic
}
```